# How to write a controller for downloading and downloading files correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails as a backend and as a frontend Angular 5. How can I correctly write a controller and routing on Rails so that in the future I could upload and download files using Angular?
A regular controller I'm using is not working:

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_file, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @files = File.all

    render json: @files
  end

def show
  render json: @file
end

def create
  @file = File.new(files_params)

  if @file.save
    render json: @file, status: :created, location: @file
  else
    render json: @file.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def update
  if @file.update(files_params)
    render json: @file
  else
    render json: @file.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end  
end

def destroy
  @file.destroy
end

private
  def set_file
    @file = File.find(params[:id])
  end

  def files_params

    params.require(:file).permit!
  end
end
```

Files:

```
ID:          NUMBER
NAME:        VARCHAR2
FILE_NAME:   VARCHAR2
CONTENT:     BLOB
FILE_TYPE:   VARCHAR2
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Brad when I want to just look at the file, it produces  error: 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1623ms

Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):

app/controllers/files_controller.rb:7:in `index'

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR:

I will do Solution 2 instead of Solution 1 unless you really intend to include the File-data as part of the JSON response.

### Solution 1: JSON includes the Base64-encoded string of the file

**app/models/file.rb:**

```
class File < ApplicationRecord
  def as_json(options = nil)
    super(
      except: [:content],
      methods: [:content_encoded]
    )
  end

  def content_encoded
    Base64.strict_encode64(content)
  end
end
```

Then, in your JS:

```
// do AJAX call to FilesController#index...
// sample JSON response:
// [
//   { "id": 1, "name": "...", "file_name": "...", "file_type": "...", "content_encoded": "SGVsbG8gCiB3b3JsZCBoYWhhaGE=", "created_at": "...", "updated_at": "..." },
//   { "id": 2, "name": "...", "file_name": "...", "file_type": "...", "content_encoded": "WW93cyB5b3dzIHlvd3Mh", "created_at": "...", "updated_at": "..." }
// ]
// then, say we now have this response body Object (named `data`)
Object.forEach(data, function(file) {
  // atob decodes Base64-encoded-string into Binary-string
  var fileContent = atob(file.content_encoded)
});
```

### Solution 2: JSON includes a URL string for the file

**app/controllers/files_controller.rb:**

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_file, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :content]

  def index
    @files = File.all

    json_response = @files.collect do |file|
      file.as_json(
        except: :content
      ).merge(
        content_url: content_file_url(file)
      )
    end

    render json: json_response
  end

  def content
    send_data @file.content
  end

  # ...
end
```

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :files do
    # will generate a route: GET /files/:id/content as `content_file_url`
    get :content, on: :member
  end
end
```

Then, in your JS

```
// do AJAX call to FilesController#index...
// sample JSON response:
// [
//   { "id": 1, "name": "...", "file_name": "...", "file_type": "...", "content_url": "http://localhost:3000/files/1/content", "created_at": "...", "updated_at": "..." },
//   { "id": 2, "name": "...", "file_name": "...", "file_type": "...", "content_url": "http://localhost:3000/files/2/content", "created_at": "...", "updated_at": "..." }
// ]
// then, say we now have the response body Object (named `data`)
Object.forEach(data, function(file) {
  console.log(file.content_url)
});
```